# Java referencing and modifying linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am a bit new to Java and one thing is currently bothering me a bit regarding referencing.

I have a method that returns `void`. I passed in a linked list to this method. There is another linked list variable called `noDuplicateLL` that references to the same linked list. `noDuplicateLL` skips nodes in the linked list.

code:

```
public static void removeDuplicate(LinkedListNode a) {
    LinkedListNode noDuplicateLL = null;
    if (a == null) {
        //return null;
    } else {
        HashMap<Integer, Boolean> duplicateCheck = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        while (a != null) {
            // check in hashtable O(1)
            if (duplicateCheck.containsKey(a.data)) {
                noDuplicateLL.next = a.next;
            } else {
                noDuplicateLL = a;
                duplicateCheck.put(a.data, true);
            }
            // update
            a = a.next;
        }
    }
}
```

`LinkedListNode a` gets iterated through the whole list. `LinkedListNode noDuplicateLL` stops moving once `a` reaches `null`. So once this method is done, both pointers are pointing somewhere else in the list, not the front.

The method below prints on the list from beginning to end.

```
public static void printLinkedList(LinkedListNode head) {
    while (head != null) {
        System.out.println(head.data);
        head = head.next;
    }
}
```

My main:

```
    LinkedListNode LL = LinkedList.randomLinkedList(nodeVal);
    removeDuplicate(LL);
    printLinkedList(LL);
```

How come the output still prints from beginning to end of the linked list when LL is passed into the method as `a`? Is it because `a` simply points to the nodes in the linked list while `LL` maintains the reference to the front of the linked list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LL --> some head node
// invoke method
// LL's value bound to parameter a
a --> some head node
// method executes
a --> head's next
a --> that next's next
...
a --> null
// method exits
```

`LL` still points to the original head node.

> Is it because a simply points to the nodes in the linked list while LL
>   maintains the reference to the front of the linked list?

Yes. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) as soon as you can.